# This android code looks fine but is not running on the emulator

Tags: android, android-intent

I created this just to understand what intents do and how they do it:

**first activity:**

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private Button launch;
  private EditText label;
  private String msg;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    launch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.launch);
    label=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    msg= label.getText().toString();

    launch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent=SecondActivity.newIntent(FirstActivity.this, msg);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**second activity:**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText et1;
  private static String EXTRA ="extra";
  private static String message="msg";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);

    message=getIntent().getStringExtra(message);
    et1.setText(message);
  }

  public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, String msg) {
    Intent i = new Intent(packageContext, SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA, msg);
    return i;
  }
}
```

and these are the xml files of the two activities(although I dont think these will be needed but if necessary):
first activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:text="First Activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Launch the second activity"
        android:id="@+id/launch"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Activity"
        android:id="@+id/et1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there is no error. The screen appearing on the emulator is just blank. Nothing at all. I debugged it, analyzed it, built it again. Nothing worked

Comment: Could you provide your `AndroidManifest.xml`? It seems there is another empty `Activity` that is set as the main activity that will be launched when the app is run.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it the regular way, don't create any method.

**In your first activity :**

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And it should work.

You can add content to your intent (like you tried with your `msg`) this way :

```
intent.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
intent.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");
```

Then **in activity 2** you retrieve the datas like this :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
  return;
}
// get data via the key
String value1 = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
if (value1 != null) {
  // do something with the data
}
```

Comment: thank you for telling about this way of using intents. But the problem is still there.  The screen appearing on the emulator is just blank. Nothing at all. I debugged it, analyzed it, built it again. Nothing worked

Comment: What is in your activity_second.xml file ? I hope that your EditText doesn't have a white color. Or maybe you have a custom theme which is white ?

Comment: Nope. I did not create any custom theme. And in the activity_second and activity_first, there are just appbaroverlay and popup overlay themes. And I didnt specify any color for editext and button but both are not appearing on the screen. It just the normal layout of a toolbar, a fab and thats it.

Comment: Can you post the whole XML of activity_first and activity_second ? Do you use any fragment or navdrawer that include any view ?

Comment: yes. I have added the xml files in the question description

Comment: and no I have not used anything else other than these files. I just made an edittext and a button for the first activity and an edittext for the second activity and made the msg in the editext pass as an intent to start the second activity when the launch button is pressed and then set the the entered text into the editext of the second activity. Its very simple yes but I dont know why it is not working in the emulator.

Comment: I'm sorry to said that, but this code work on my side. So you have an emulator problem. Try to reboot your PC or test it with a real device or use Genymotion (a good emulator !)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {     
  Intent intent=SecondActivity.newIntent(FirstActivity.this, targetActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: should work. But the widgets dont appear in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button launch;
private EditText label;
private String msg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

launch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.launch);
label=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);


launch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     msg= label.getText().toString();
      Intent intent=SecondActivity.newIntent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("msg",msg);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 });
 }
 }
```

Comment: I wont know if this works or not (it does logically) until the widgets appear in the emulator and they are not appearing.